# Updating EF 4.6 edmx model in VS 2015

Tags: entity-framework-4, visual-studio-2015, ef-database-first

We have a legacy EF 4.6 project not yet migrated to a newer version of EF.
Now I want to update the model from the database (add a new table) so I open the EDMX in the designer like in VS 2010 and choose "Update from the database". This gives me a warning that "Your project references an older version of Entity Framework. ..."

The only choice in this update from the database action it gives me is EF 5.0 but I need EF 4.6

Is it possible somehow to make the model update in the designer without upgrading to a newer version of EF or using an older version of VS?

Comment: there is no EF4.6. Last is EF 4.3.1: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/4.3.1

Answer (score 1):

I have just come up against the same problem (although I was stuck on v4.0.0.0). The solution was to install [ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=8363).

This put the required tooling on my computer and allowed me to update my model.